# $f$ continuous on open set implies locally Lipschitz. What additional condition will make it true?

Tags: continuity, lipschitz-functions

Is it true that if $f:O_{\text{open}}\subset\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$ is continuous then it is locally Lipschitz?

Maybe the function $f(x)=\sin(1/x)\cdot x$ is a counter example because at $x=0$ we can find a sequence $x_n\rightarrow 0$ such that  $|f'(x_n)|\rightarrow\infty$ so there is no neighborhood of $0$ such that Lipschitz condition holds.

Is there an additional condition we could impose to make the statement true?

Comment: $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$ is a counter example, it is not (locally) Lipschitz at $x=0$.

Comment: What kind of “additional condition” are you looking for? What about “$f$ is differentiable and the derivative is locally bounded”?

Comment: I was looking for something that's not as obvious as "derivative is locally bounded"